# VueJS not working properly in laravel

Tags: vue.js

I have this code in app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import Buefy from 'buefy';
Vue.use(Buefy);

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {} 
});
```

in master page I used Yield before closing body tag:

```
@yield('scripts')
```

and in a view page I tried to use Vue like this:

```
@section('scripts')
  <script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      permission: true
    }
  });
  </script>
@endsection
```

But it gives this error:

> ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

I can't figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Either the you don't have vue.min.js in your `<script>` tag in or you don't include `import vue from vue` in your app.js.

Comment: I have both script tag and Vue library

Comment: I think you need only one if you're using library you only need to use `import/require` then use `<div id="app">` in your `blade.php`. You're declaring two Vue `#app`s.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following before your script -

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already included Vue like this 

    window.Vue = require('vue');

and I have script tag in master page:

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>